# ゲームオーバーになったら画面を初期化する方法

Tags: java

java初心者です、アドベンチャーゲームを作っているのですが
ゲームオーバーになった時にタイトル画面に戻したいです
なので

```
pChild.removeAll();
jpChild.add(jlChild);
jpChild2.removeAll();
jpChild2.add(jlMain);
```

としたのですが、反映されていませんでした。
どうしてでしょうか？
そして進む時と戦闘処理のようなものをZキーでしているのですが
コードがとてもわかりづらく幼稚なものになってしまいます。
このコードの改善点を教えてください。知恵を貸してください…

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

    //省略

    case KeyEvent.VK_Z :
        if (joutai == 0){
            Programer(HP,IQ,EQ,kyori);
            kyori++;    //進む
            jlMain.setText(Programer(HP,IQ,EQ,kyori));
            int ran = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            if (ran == 1){
                jlChild.setText(PutEnemy(JHP,JIQ));
                joutai = joutai + 1;
            }
        }
        if(joutai == 1){
            JHP = JHP - IQ;
            jlChild.setText(PutEnemy(JHP,JIQ));
            HP = HP - JIQ;
            if (HP <=0 ){
                jlChild.setText("GAME OVER");
                jpChild.removeAll();
                jpChild.add(jlChild);
                jpChild2.removeAll();
                jpChild2.add(jlMain);
            }
        }
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのコードですが、Javaと言っても色々ありますので、どういうライブラリ等を使ってどういう形で組んでいるのかが伝わらないとなかなか答えにくいのではないかと思います。もし参考にしている書籍・Webページがあるのでしたら、それを追記してください。また、Javaだとプログラムの冒頭でimportしているものを列挙して頂ければ、使っているライブラリが分かるのではと思います（今回の場合、javax.swing.*あたりをご使用なのでしょうか？）。自分の質問は質問の下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、お試しください。

Comment: `jlChild.setText("GAME OVER");` の部分は期待通り動作しているのでしょうか？

Comment: 返信遅れてごめんなさい、その部分は表示されます。質問を取り消したいのですが取り消すことはできますか？

Comment: もしhiroさんが何か行って解決したのであれば、[自己回答が推奨されています](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)ので、是非自己回答していただけませんでしょうか？